# How do i use JPA specific API for Query Cache in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, caching, orm

```
public class Application1{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("infinite");
        EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
        /*
        *
        * */

        Query query = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT key from KeyValue ");
        org.hibernate.Query hquery = query.unwrap(org.hibernate.Query.class);
        hquery.setCacheable(true);

        List<String> list = query.getResultList();
        list.forEach(System.out::println);


        Query query1 = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT key from KeyValue ");
        org.hibernate.Query hquery1 = query.unwrap(org.hibernate.Query.class);
        hquery1.setCacheable(true);

        query.setHint("org.hibernate.cacheable", Boolean.TRUE);
        List<String> list1 = query1.getResultList();
        list1.forEach(System.out::println);


    }
}
```

**Here I have to unwrap hibernate Query class , is there any other way to do it if i use JPA as specification with hibernate**

Comment: no idea what that means. JPA provides query hints to set vendor specifics.

Comment: Example that i shown you , is that only way to do Query Cache in hibernate ?

Answer (score 0):

No you can't do query result set caching with plain `JPA`.

P.S. Have you put the `hibernate.cache.use_query_cache="true"` in your configuration file if you are using `setCacheable(true)`?

Comment: Yes i am doing , This code working properly . The only problem i have i do not want to do this(org.hibernate.Query hquery = query.unwrap(org.hibernate.Query.class this unwrapping )) .

Comment: @MohammadFaizan Unluckily you have to use the Hibernate Query object, as I stated in the answer plain JPA doesn't support result set caching.